# Unable to locate CSS error ({ expected) in SCSS file

Tags: html, css, sass, scss-mixins

I'm super noob at coding and building a project for my SCSS/CSS Course so this might come up as a super easy even dumb question for most of you so here we go.

**I'm getting this error in my CSS file but I'm unable to determine what to edit in my SCSS file to resolve it.**

Here's my code for CSS from line 51 to 55 (where the error is displayed):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9agzC.png)

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  :hover {
    color: pink;
   }
  }
```

And here's my SCSS code from where I *think* it might be coming from though I don't really know how to solve it:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfVGo.png)

```
    @mixin mobile {
    @media screen and(max-width: $mobile){
      @content;  
     }
    }
```

My Github repository for the project can be found here: https://github.com/Romxh/RevisionOficial if more details need to be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you aren't targetting anything. See my example where I used a div as a target here :

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

.div{
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;}
```

Comment: Thanks Usama! I do see the error in CSS though what I'm not able is to solve it in SCSS. This CSS file is created automatically from SCSS. 
If I edit it on my .css file it'll all be wiped out when .scss is saved once again

Comment: If i put the css into a scss converter it gives the same out like this
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .div {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
 }
}

Sorry that I couldn't help you :(

Comment: Good catch Usama. I would have skimmed right over that